# What does expiration mean in boto3 Amazon S3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to set an expiration date/time to files after they have been created in Amazon S3. the expiration time that I placed is just 5 to 10 seconds right after the file has been "put" in Amazon S3.

but contrary to my expectation, after a couple of minutes when I try to list the objects under the prefix that I use, the files that I thought should already be deleted are still there.

upon checking, expire means that the file won't be cacheable anymore. what does that mean? when will that expired file be totally deleted from the bucket?

I use client's get_object to reveal the expiration value, expiration is described here and some aws s3 docs also mentions the term *no longer cacheable* which I totally don't get: [link](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object)

this is how I upload data:

```
s3_client.put_object(Body=data, Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
s3_client.copy_object(CopySource=f"{bucket}/{key}",
                      Bucket=bucket,
                      Key=key,
                      Metadata={'expires': expiration},
                      MetadataDirective='REPLACE')
```

when I try to get my files, it does show a past date and time so I do think that I placed the correct expiration value on the object. I'm just wondering why it still shows when I try to list the objects in a specific folder/prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> expire means that the file won't be cacheable anymore. what does that mean?

This is only end-user helper argument. It does not do anything by itself. It means that who/what ever is going to use the copied object, should do so before it expires. After that date, the file maybe outdated and new copy should be made. In terms of AWS, its useful in [CouldFront caching](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html#ExpirationAddingHeadersInS3) to indicate when CF should discard expired s3 files.

To properly auto-delete (aka expire) your objects you have to set [s3 lifecycle rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-expire-general-considerations.html).